# mysql row constructor query get incorrect result when using subquery that contain group by clause

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

i use row constructor syntax, when the subquery end with `group by`, then it return empty result, when comment the `group by`, then result is correct. the distinct in the two statement is the comment line.

the statement get correct result

```
 SELECT a.ChannelId, a.GoodsId FROM t_test a
 WHERE 1=1 
 AND (a.ChannelId, a.GoodsId) NOT IN (
 SELECT ChannelId, GoodsId FROM (SELECT  ChannelId, GoodsId FROM t_test 
 WHERE (IFNULL(twoNotQuantity, 0) + IFNULL(twoCheckQuantity, 0)) > 0 
-- GROUP BY ChannelId, GoodsId
) b
);
```

[image]

the statement get incorrect result

```
 SELECT a.ChannelId, a.GoodsId FROM t_test a
 WHERE 1=1 
 AND (a.ChannelId, a.GoodsId) NOT IN (
 SELECT ChannelId, GoodsId FROM (SELECT  ChannelId, GoodsId FROM t_test 
 WHERE (IFNULL(twoNotQuantity, 0) + IFNULL(twoCheckQuantity, 0)) > 0 
GROUP BY ChannelId, GoodsId
) b
);
```

[image]

the subquery statement

```
 SELECT ChannelId, GoodsId FROM (SELECT  ChannelId, GoodsId FROM t_test 
 WHERE (IFNULL(twoNotQuantity, 0) + IFNULL(twoCheckQuantity, 0)) > 0 
GROUP BY ChannelId, GoodsId
) b;
```

[image: subquery statement resultset]

my table ddl

```
CREATE TABLE `t_test` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ChannelId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `GoodsId` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `twoNotQuantity` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twoCheckQuantity` decimal(20,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1894 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

my data

```
INSERT INTO demo.t_test (ChannelId,GoodsId,twoNotQuantity,twoCheckQuantity) VALUES
     (2129504377563648,2129456810682880,NULL,98.0000),
     (2129504377563648,2089744751847936,NULL,98.0000),
     (2129504377563648,2067916860058112,NULL,NULL);
```

i know the statement is a bad sql, but i want to know which case it trigger such scenarios, and whether any limitation about row constructor syntax that i should avoid. i reading the offical document, and not found about the useful info.

Comment: Adding to the peculiarity, without the trivial additional nest to the subquery both work in 8.0. And up to 5.7 in a fiddle both of your queries yield the same result as is. It's documented that aggregate behavior for IN/NOT IN subqueries ,changed in 8.0 . But the nitty gritty isn't really covered.

Comment: To this part of the question though: "whether any limitation about row constructor syntax that i should avoid" Yes, I'd just throw this on the overflowing pile of reasons to never use NOT IN. As a rule for a few other reasons (performance in some cases, ease of troubleshooting, insane NULL behavior) I never us NOT IN unless it's for a hardcoded list. Anti-join idioms and NOT EXIST are categorically better. But this is a very well-posed question illustrating some very odd behavior.

Comment: @Error_2646 i find the two statement yield the same result when in MySQL 8.0.20.  if the case is the bug about mysql, or just the query behavior like these is undefind

Comment: I figure it must be a configuration difference, probably with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY based on the documentation. But I don't have MySQL locally and couldn't force it in a fiddle. What version were you using when you got the difference and the content of your sql_mode variable?

Comment: in 8.0.20 it is `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`, in 8.2.0 it is `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: That explains it. At least the difference, still logically strange I agree.